# How to call a custom Python script in Logstash to transform few columns in a huge csv file?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to Logstash and just exploring it.

I have a huge csv file with a million rows and bit more. It has around 40 columns. Few of them are strings and few are numbers.

Now, before I index this csv file into ElasticSearch, I want to add another extra 2 columns whose values are derived based on some custom logic written in Python. The Python script basically looks at the content at few other columns and based on that decides what the value in the new columns are.

Now, what is exactly required in LogStash to be able to do this? Should we write a custom filter and if so would it be possible to call the script in Logstash such that it processes the csv file as fast as it can?

Thanks

Comment: This should help: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-call-python-script-from-logstash-to-process-partialy-logs/40009/2

Comment: You could convert your python code to ruby and use the ruby filter.

Comment: @baudsp, so is it not possible to refer to a Python script?

Comment: Why don't you read the csv with the csv filter and use if / else afterwards? You also can add stuff to the csv file with "add_field"

Comment: @Londonguy From the link Val posted, it should be possible, but I've never used it. I only pointed what I would have done in such case (this or what HauLuk posted)